# Flutter Can we use ontap and onchanged property simultaneously on the single TextField?

Tags: flutter, frontend, flutter-layout

```dart
return TextField(
  // something
  onTap: ()  {
    // something something 
  },
  onChanged: (value) {
    // some if else nesteing 
  },
)
```

This is my code I want to know if we can use `onTap` and `onChange` on the same `TextField`.

Comment: Yes, you can. If you've got any issue, please consider including [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) while asking question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is Yes. According to the documentation,

```
onChanged → ValueChanged<String>?
Called when the user initiates a change to the TextField's value: when they have inserted or deleted text. [...]

onTap → GestureTapCallback?
Called for each distinct tap except for every second tap of a double tap. [...]
```

They both perform completely different functions on a TextField widget.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html

##### Updated to reflect necessity from the comment section

If you want to do something after the user is done typing, I would recommend using a delay / Debouncer. Like https://gist.github.com/venkatd/7125882a8e86d80000ea4c2da2c2a8ad

```
final _debouncer = Debouncer(delay: const Duration(seconds: 1));

TextField(
  onChanged: (_value) {
    _debouncer(() {
      setState(() {
        print(_value);
      });
    });
  },
);
```

Comment: I  using set state inside ontap and our value toogle  normally but when i use onchange on this textfield the apps functionality misbehaves.

Comment: It's not recommended to use setState inside the onChanged method as it'll be called everytime the value of the TextField widget changes. Say for example you want to type: `Hello World`, setState will be called 11 times. This is not very optimal, performance-wise.

Comment: But if you want to do something after the user is done typing, I would recommend using a delay / Debouncer. Like https://gist.github.com/venkatd/7125882a8e86d80000ea4c2da2c2a8ad

Comment: @VarunBhardwaj I updated my answer to reflect this with an example

Comment: The thing is I  have a date picker field set nd  by ontap i trigger the date picker to  let user selects the date from the calendar and after ok it's should reflects on there. So. I need to rebuild the screen with this data that's why i used setstate inside the ontap.

Comment: Just to put it out there, if what you are trying to accomplish is to show a datepicker dialog, then I'll suggest you use the `showDatePicker` helper function that does exactly this and has lots of customisation params.